# Map function increment on global react context state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I need some help with incrementing a value through map function while using React's context API. Here is an example to better understand:
Let's say I have items:

```
const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemsContext)
```

These items are JSON objects inside an array.
And then I want to return each item's properties in a list but some of them modified - for example, the item has quantity and I want to increment/decrement it on click. How do I achieve this individually for every item?

I tried making a local state for the quantities:

```
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState([])
```

,so I have all the quantities of all elements but it got me nowhere.

The thing I am trying to accomplish is similar to this:

```
<div>
<ul>
{
 items.map(item => (
 <li>
     <p>item.name</p>
     <p>item.quantity</p>
     <button onClick={incQuantity}>  </button>
 </li>
 }
</ul>
</div>
```

Edit:

```
const [idCounter, setIdCounter] = useState(0)
```

I use props. here because this is another component.

```
const addItem = () => {
        if (quantity > 0) {
            setIdCounter(idCounter + 1)
            setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, {id: idCounter, name: props.name, price: props.price, quantity: quantity }])
        }
    }
```

And I implemented the handler quite the same:

```
const quantityHandler = (id, diff) => {
    setItems(items.map((item) => 
        item.id === id ? {...item, quantity: item.quantity + diff} : item
    ))
}
```

And here is the list itself:

```
<div>
<ul>
{
 items.map(item => (
 <li>
     <p>item.name</p>
     <p>item.quantity</p>
     <button onClick={() => quantityHandler(item.id, 1)}>  </button>
     <button onClick={() => quantityHandler(item.id, -1)}>  </button>
 </li>
 }
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example and I will explain it a little: in `App` we make MyContext and state with hook, then we provide state and function to update state to Context provider as `value`. Then in any place inside Provider we have access to that state and setter. We render items and we can update them using hook setter from Context.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";

const MyContext = React.createContext(null);

const initialState = [
  { id: 1, quantity: 1 },
  { id: 2, quantity: 2 },
  { id: 3, quantity: 3 },
  { id: 4, quantity: 4 },
];

const DeepNestedComponent = () => {
  const [stateFromContext, setStateFromContext] = useContext(MyContext);
  // MyContext should be imported

  const buttonHandler = (id, diff) => {
    setStateFromContext(
      stateFromContext.map((item) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + diff } : item
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {stateFromContext.map(({ id, quantity }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          {quantity}
          <button onClick={() => buttonHandler(id, 1)}> + </button>
          <button onClick={() => buttonHandler(id, -1)}> - </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [contextState, setContextState] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={[contextState, setContextState]}>
      <DeepNestedComponent />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Like it if its is working )

Comment: Yes, I tried something similar, but not quite like this approach with the ids. I will try it and text back with info! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would work if I were using static context state, but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: what do you mean? which context are you using ? can you provide code?

Comment: I still managed to make dynamic ids, and I get this error : Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: I will edit the question with more info, hope it helps.

Comment: And I dont even have useEffect implemented, which makes this error more confusing.

Comment: It works, I edited it the right way but in my code the second onClick wasnt an anonymous function, it just right away called quantityHandler. Adding it as anonymous call fixed it.